# Is there a way to build a portable RIA without using LiveCycle?

Tags: pdf, ria, portability

I saw your article on portable RIAs.  Excellent article!
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/portable_ria.html

We don't have LiveCycle, but want to allow our users to view a Flex App inside PDF without an internet connection.

Is there another way like using Cold Fusion, AlivePDF, to accomplish the PDF Generation part of your article?   It is not clear if there is something unique to LiveCycle or maybe we can just embed the swf and use existing CF8 PDF capabilities.  A

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that you can use [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) to do the PDF generation which embeds a SWF.  But I haven't tried it myself.